# ATTiny and Linux AVR-GCC interrupt reset vector in linker

Tags: linux, reset, boot, avr, avr-gcc

at this site http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/Konzept_f%C3%BCr_einen_ATtiny-Bootloader_in_C (sorry it's in German, I had to use google translator) it's described a way of changing the reset address value when linking the code by using:

```
-Wl,--section-start=.bootreset=0x00
```

and then, in the code, we define the bootreset value to be:

```
uint16_t boot_reset __attribute__((section(".bootreset"))) = 0xC000U + 0x1800 / 2 - 1;
```

where 0x1800 is our code start.

I tried this in Atmel Studio and it works exactly as it says, but on linux using avr.gcc 4.5 it doesn't :S

Anyone know how can I make this work in linux avr-gcc, preferably both (win and linux) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of digging I found the answer.

the avr-objcopy command line arguments I was using were only including specific sections in the code conversion to hex, like -j .text etc, thus leaving out the custom .bootreset section.

on Atmel Studio, the default behaviour is exclude certain sections by using -R so, the custom section above would be included.

To have this custom sections added on the hex, just -j (or -J can't remember now) .bootreset on avr-objcopy.